# Why does Tensorflow 1.11.0 return CUDA_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, tesla

My machine is **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**, with CUDA has been successfully installed. The output of `$nvcc --version` is

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

I have two GPUs of Tesla K80, and the command **nvidia-smi** shows:

[output of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifbHG.png)

I also tried to test with `./deviceQuery` from `NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples` and its output is as the followings:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 2 CUDA Capable device(s)`

...

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 2
Result = PASS
```

However, once I install Tensorflow GPU `version 1.11.0` from pip, I couldn't open a Tensorflow session.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

and it outputs:

```
2018-11-15 00:13:46.593039: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/quoctin.phan/tools/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_1.11/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1511, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/quoctin.phan/tools/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_1.11/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 634, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED: operation not supported
```

I have tried to reinstall Tensorflow 1.12.0, but nothing changes. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think your problem might be somehow connected to Compute Capability? The problem is described in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22594).

You can check them when you run deviceQuery.exe. [Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024645/compute-capability-check/) is a thread about where to find it on windows distribution of CUDA package.

Comment: I was able to solve it. The problem was the mismatch between NVIDIA-SMI version and Driver Version ([here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76h0oloi2dtykpb/Screenshot%202018-11-15%2010.51.18.png?dl=0)). Thank you!